# How to convert utc time into ist in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, utc

Hi I am trying to convert `utc` datetime to `ist` time.
Here is what i tried

```
SELECT payment_date,((payment_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'IST') AS local_timestamp
FROM pos_payment where DATE(payment_date) >='2022-02-16';
```

Output is:

```
  payment_date           local_timestamp
  ----------------- --------------------
 "2022-02-16 07:18:17"  "2022-02-16 09:18:17"
 "2022-02-16 07:18:27"  "2022-02-16 09:18:27"
 "2022-02-16 07:27:52"  "2022-02-16 09:27:52"
```

Expected output:

```
 local_timestamp
 -----------------
 "2022-02-16 12:48:17"
 "2022-02-16 09:48:27"
 "2022-02-16 09:57:52"
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Why did you expect that output with Israel Standard Time? Obviously it's not Irish Summer Time. Italy Standard Time?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I thought `IST` means Indian standardtime. i quried the abbrivation using  this command, `select * from pg_timezone_names order by name`.

Comment: Now i tried with `Asia/Calcutta` isntead of `IST`. Now its working.

Comment: Did you check the results of that query? `select * from pg_timezone_names where abbrev='IST'` returns 5 results, 3 for Israel, 2 for India.

Comment: The 3-letter abbreviations are just that - abbreviations, not standard timezone names. Lots of countries can use the same abbreviation. Use the IANA timezones instead. If you look at Wikipedia's [List of Timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) you'll find 3 countries use IST: Ireland, Israel, India

Answer (score 2):

I used the full name of timezone `Asia/Kolkata` instead of abbreviation `IST`. Now it is working.

```
SELECT payment_date,
       ((payment_date
            AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
                AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'
       ) AS local_timestamp
FROM pos_payment
where DATE(payment_date) >='2022-02-16';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the IANA timezone names instead. These are the defacto standard for timezone names:

```
SELECT payment_date,
       ((payment_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta') AS local_timestamp
FROM pos_payment where DATE(payment_date) >='2022-02-16';
```

The 3-letter abbreviations are just that - abbreviations, not standard, unique timezone names. Lots of countries can use the same abbreviation.  If you look at Wikipedia's [List of Timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) you'll find 3 countries use IST: Ireland, Israel, India

```
IST Indian Standard Time    UTC+05:30
IST Irish Standard Time[8]  UTC+01
IST Israel Standard Time    UTC+02
```

From the same article :

> Time zones are often represented by alphabetic abbreviations such as "EST", "WST", and "CST", but these are not part of the international time and date standard ISO 8601 and their use as sole designator for a time zone is discouraged.

The [IANA timezone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) should be used instead, eg `Asia/Kolkata` or `Asia/Tel_Aviv`. These aren't part of a standard like ISO8601, but they're used everywhere, becoming a de-facto standard. All Unix and Linux systems use the IANA timezone database.

In PostgreSQL, the query

```
select * from pg_timezone_names where abbrev='IST' order by name
```

Returns 5 results :

```
name            abbrev  utc_offset               is_dst
Asia/Calcutta   IST     {"hours":5,"minutes":30} false
Asia/Jerusalem  IST     {"hours":2}              false
Asia/Kolkata    IST     {"hours":5,"minutes":30} false
Asia/Tel_Aviv   IST     {"hours":2}              false
Israel          IST     {"hours":2}              false
```